# Strange authentication error in laravel when online webserver. App working on local server

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

> ErrorException in EloquentUserProvider.php line 114: Argument 1 passed
>   to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() must be
>   an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of
>   App\Users given, called in
>   /home/a100ramd/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php
>   on line 378 and defined

I have seen many posts complaining of the same problem. Mine is a bit different. When I use the app on localhost, it works nicely. But when I use the app online after uploading it to my webhost, this error occurs.

The problem occurs only when the correct login credentials are given. When the incorrect login credentials are entered, the control goes to the 'else ' part of the condition.

Admin model:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
protected $fillable=[
    'mobileNumber',
    'password',
    'balance',
];
}
```

Users model:

```
namespace App;
```

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

```
class Users extends Model
{
protected $fillable=[
    'firstName',
    'lastName',
    'mobileNumber',
    'password',
    'isActive',
    'balance',
    'referrer',
    'parent',
    'level',
];

public function scopeLevel($query, $level)
{
    return $query->where('level', $level);
}

public function scopeOrphan($query)
{
    return $query->where('parent',null)->where('isActive','0');
}
}
```

Sign In function in the controller:

```
 public function adminSignIn(Request $request)
{
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'mobileNumber' => 'required|min:10',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return Redirect::to('admin')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput(Input::except('password'));
    } else {
        $admindata = array(
            'mobileNumber' => Input::get('mobileNumber'),
            'password' => Input::get('password')
        );

        if (Auth::attempt($admindata)) {
            if (Auth::user()->isAdmin == '1') {
                return Redirect::to('admin_index');
            } else {
                return Redirect::to('admin');
            }

        } else {
            echo 'Failure';
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to solve this problem since the last 24 hours, but had to finally post it. Please help. My whole project is working on local server. This is my last step. Thanks!

Comment: did you use this trait on your model ```use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;```

Comment: Please post the contents of the `providers` key from `config/auth.php`.

Comment: providers from config/auth.php:
    `'providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\User::class,
            'model' => App\Users::class,
        ],`
@Bogdan

Comment: @ImtiazPabel Yes, I tried using the trait. In the IDE, it shows that the it is never used. But no difference in the result even after adding the use statement on the web server.

Comment: And are those setting from `config/auth.php` the same on your production server as in your local environment?

Comment: @Bogdan By mistake, I have given the Admin model, but in providers only User class is given. But the problem persists even when logging in as a user.

Comment: @Bogdan Yes, the values are the same in the production server. [img]http://i.imgur.com/0mJlyQn.png[/img] (Screenshot of the file data on the production server) Just in case, my eyes weren't able to figure out.

Comment: If the Eloquent model configured to be used is `App\Users` then that class **must** extend the [`Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/User.php) model which implements the necessary interfaces and includes the proper traits that are needed by the authentication system.

Comment: Currently you have this `class Users extends Model`, when you should have this `class Users extends Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User`. Also having two `model` keys in your auth config `providers` array is useless because only the last one is taken into consideration. The [default `User` model that comes with Laravel](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/master/app/User.php) implements this properly. Is there any reason you're not using that model?

Comment: @Bogdan Tried extending Illuminate\.....\User
Now, the sign in fails even if correct login credentials are being entered.
Confimed the input by dd($userdata).

Comment: I have created all my models using the `php artisan make:model` command. It is the model created by default. I just change the varibles in the protected array when making a new model.

Comment: @Vivek And it fails with an exception or just the `attempt` method call returns false?

Comment: @Vivek Also, using the `make:model` artisan command is fine for regular models, however the authentication system requires extra methods implemented on a model, that's why Laravel comes with that default `User` model I've linked to in my previous comments that extends the auth foundation user model.

Comment: @Bogdan No exception. The control goes to the else part. The method call returns false.

Comment: @Vivek and I assume the password was hashed  using `bcrypt`, before being stored in the database. Also on that note, did you change at any point the `APP_KEY` in the `.env` file?

Comment: @Bogdan Yes, the password was indeed hashed. The APP_KEY should have changed as I was facing problems directly uploading the laravel files to the server. So I installed a new copy of laravel using Softaculous. And so, I created a temporary page just to save admin username and password to mysql on the server (to save bcrypt'ed password to db). I am trying logging in using the credentials stored by this temporary page. Meanwhile, let me check the `APP_KEY` in the `.env` file.

Comment: @Bogdan Oh my gosh! The .env file is not at all present on the production server. Is this even possible ? Can laravel app run without the .env file ?

Comment: Sure Laravel can run without any `.env` file, as there are defaults stored for all necessary configuration settings within the config files themselves. That's why for ex. in `config/database.php` you have `'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost')`, the `env` helper function checks for the `DB_HOST` key in the `.env` file and if it doesn't find one it uses the second parameter `localhost` as the value (although the defaults only work properly with [Homestead](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/homestead)). Also, ignore my previous comment about the `APP_KEY` as I realised it's not relevant in this case.

Comment: But then, without the `.env` file, we do not have an `APP_KEY` at all. Even in the `config/app.php` file, the key is fetched from the `.env` file. (`'key' => env('APP_KEY'),`

If the `.env` is not the problem, what is the problem ?

Comment: Does creating a new user and trying to log in with those new credentials work?

Comment: I did that before posting. But still, will do that again right now and confirm.

Comment: No, logging in with newly created credentials, failed.

Comment: @Bogdan The surprise is how come it works on local server but not on the production server ?

Comment: @Bogdan Okay, thank you for your wonderful support. Actually I was hashing the password twice before entering the same in database. Solved it.